# how to get the name of an element in javascript created within it

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am making a javscript library like reactJS. And, I am stuck with a problem.

```
//how to get the name of an element created in javascript in another function without parameter

//Example
let demo = document.createElement("div"):

function example(element){
  // this will get the name of the element ,ie.., div
  console.log(...)
  //should print "div" on the console
}
example(demo);
```

Can anybody help me?

`Edit: This is just an example. The libray is more complex and long that I cant add it here.`

Comment: what is you expected output?

Comment: It's not clear what you need.. 
In "function example" the variable "demo" is visible, so you can print it.

Comment: `console.log(element.nodeName);`.

Comment: May I ask what the use-case for this is? The element-type (`div`, `span`, `input`...) is trivially obtained from a property of the given element (which may make the use of a function unnecessary), also: if you're creating the element (particularly if that's within the same function/context) doesn't your code already "know" what element it's creating?

Comment: This is just an example. The library I am making is more complex.

Comment: Of course, but if we know your use-case we may be able to offer a better, more flexible, answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the element.localName, element.nodeName or element.tagName:

```js
function example(element){
  console.log(element.localName); // should print 'div'
  console.log(element.nodeName); // should print 'DIV'
  console.log(element.tagName); // should print 'DIV'

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This will help my library to function more powerfully with shorter code.

Comment: Bear in mind that there's also `element.tagName`, though you may want to use `element.tagName.toLowerCase()` to retrieve the lowercase name.